# How to use libtidy with tidyParseBuffer()?

Tags: html, c, stream, tidy

I'm trying to clean some HTML with libtidy (C language), the problem is:

I want to construct a TidyDoc (a tree-like structure) with tidyParseBuffer().

I have no problem with tidyParseFile(); about tidyParseBuffer(): I'm sure I read the file properly and that the TidyBuffer structure I give to tidyParseBuffer() is correctly filled.

Any ideas?

here is the code:

```
    //declaration
 tidyInput = malloc(sizeof(TidyBuffer));
 tidyOutput = malloc(sizeof(TidyBuffer));
 do { 
      len = fread(pbInputData, 1, nInputData, h->file);
      tidyBufAttach(tidyInput, (void*)pbInputData, len);
      tidyParseBuffer(h->doc, tidyInput);  // doc is the TidyDoc 
 } while (len >= nInputData);
 tidyOptSetBool(h->doc, TidyForceOutput, yes);

 tidySaveFile(handler->doc, "C://test.xhtml");
```

I did simplify the code.

Comment: Could you give an indication of the problem you are encountering, with some source code if possible?

Comment: I don't know how to put code into the comments, so I'll try to explain.

It's like the TidyDoc structure is erased at each call to tidyParseBuffer.. maybe it's the correct behavior of the function.. dunno, gonna check tidyParseStdin

Comment: Could you update the question with the code?

Comment: what I do: I fread a file into a buffer, I attach that buffer to a TidyBuffer struct, and then I tidyParseBuffer this structure with the TidyDoc structure.
while the end of the file.
and at each turn the TidyDoc struct seems to be reset.

Comment: From the function signature it seems reasonable to overwrite the passed-in `TidyDoc` each time `tidyParseBuffer()` is called. I'd expect the same behaviour from `tidyParseFile()` - are you saying that it does something different?

Comment: Not at all, but I thought that tidyParseBuffer was building the tree, adding node to the TidyDoc struct each time it was called.

Comment: The two lines `(*done) = (len <nInputData)` and `while (!done)` look dubious (different levels of indirection). Probably a result of the code simplification, but I thought it worth pointing out.

Comment: You're right about this, it is dubious, and It's come from the code simplification.. ( if you want to know where it's come from, I'm using my own api, and one of the api Call has &done as argument ..
I don't know if it's clear, but I'll edit the example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that you are trying to parse the contents of a file in chunks, reading each chunk into a buffer and calling `tidyParseBuffer()` for each chunk.

The `tidyParseXxx()` functions operate by parsing the whole input in a single call, so to do what you want you should take a look at [`TidyInputSource`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/api/struct__TidyInputSource.html) and [`tidyParseSource()`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/api/group__Parse.html#ga65dad2a4ca5fa97d267ddefe1180e0e).

Comment: It's a bit more complicated to set up but it sounds like the implementation of `tidyParseFile()` uses exactly this mechanism.